# Как сделать hover эффект для поля ввода а не всей формы?

Tags: html, css, css3

Решил добавить форму поиска в модальном окне на сайт, все получилось, но когда я захотел добавить ховер эффекты элементам формы, столкнулся с трудностями, так как тот ховер эффект котрый я решил добавить действует на всю форму (линия подчеркивания ниже под кнопкой искать) а не на конкретно поле ввода, + эта линия появляется при наведении на кнопку (на кнопку будет отдельный эффект), я пробовал применять этот эффект только к отдельному элементу input в форме, но тогда эффект вообще отсутствует, подскажите как применить этот эффект правильно, чтоб работало как планировалось? Ниже разметка модального окна с формой и стили (также добавил этот пример в codepen https://codepen.io/dlecode/pen/zaegby)

HTML

```
<label class="btn" for="modal-1">Открыть</label>
<!-- Модальное окно -->
<div class="modal">
  <input class="modal-open" id="modal-1" type="checkbox" hidden>
  <div class="modal-wrap" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    <label class="modal-overlay" for="modal-1"></label>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Поиск по сайту </h2>
        <label class="btn-close" for="modal-1" aria-hidden="true"></label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

         <!--Форма поиска-->    

                    <form class="searchtop" method="post">  

                           <input class="searchtop" autocomplete="off" name="story" placeholder="Введите ваш запрос..." type="search">
                           <input  type="hidden" name="do" value="search" >
                           <input  type="hidden" name="subaction" value="search" >
                            <button type="submit" id="btntop">Найти</button>
                   </form>



      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.searchtop {width: 100%; height: 44px; line-height: 44px; border: none; border-radius: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; background: transparent; color:#fff;  font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 30px;}

#btntop { width: 100%;  border: 1px solid #fff; background: transparent; vertical-align: middle; }


/*Hover эффект*/
.searchtop:after{
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    width: 0%;
    left:50%;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
.searchtop:hover:after{width: 100%;}


/* Стили модального окна */
.modal-header h2 {
    color: #fff;  
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;    
    margin: 0;
}
/* кнопка закрытия окна */
.modal .btn-close:before {
    content: '\2715';
    font-family: FontAwesome ;
     font-size: 1.7em;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 44px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: -5px;
}
.modal .btn-close:hover {
   text-shadow: 0 0px 10px  #fff; tansition: all .3s linear; -webkit-transition: all .3s linear; -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
}
/* слой затемнения */
.modal-wrap:before {
    content: "";
    display: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 101;
}
.modal-overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 102;
}
/* активация слоя затемнения и модального блока */
.modal-open:checked ~ .modal-wrap:before,
.modal-open:checked ~ .modal-wrap .modal-overlay {
    display: block;
}
.modal-open:checked ~ .modal-wrap .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    top: 20%;
}
/* элементы модального окна */
.modal-dialog {
    background: radial-gradient( #3daee7, #1070b9);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 500px;
    left: 50%;
    top: -100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-out;
    z-index: 103;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 0 20px 75px 20px ;
}


.modal-header h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
   padding: 15px 20px 30px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}




.btn-search {background: radial-gradient( #3daee7, #1070b9); border-radius: 22px; color:#FFF; width:44px; height:44px; line-height:44px; text-align: center; font-size:24px; display: block; cursor: pointer;}
.btn-search:hover{text-shadow: 0 0px 10px  #fff; tansition: all .3s linear; -webkit-transition: all .3s linear; -moz-transition: all .3s linear; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Линия под полем:

```css
.searchtop {width: 100%; height: 44px; line-height: 44px; border: none; border-radius: 0; position: relative; outline: 0; background: transparent; color:#fff;  font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 30px;}

#btntop { width: 100%;  border: 1px solid #fff; background: transparent; vertical-align: middle; }


/*Hover эффект*/
.searchline{
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 0%;
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 44px;
    -webkit-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
form input:hover + .searchline{width: 100%;}


/* Стили модального окна */
.modal-header h2 {
    color: #fff;  
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;    
    margin: 0;
}
/* кнопка закрытия окна */
.modal .btn-close:before {
    content: '\2715';
    font-family: FontAwesome ;
     font-size: 1.7em;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 44px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: -5px;
}
.modal .btn-close:hover {
   text-shadow: 0 0px 10px  #fff; tansition: all .3s linear; -webkit-transition: all .3s linear; -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
}
/* слой затемнения */
.modal-wrap:before {
    content: "";
    display: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 101;
}
.modal-overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 102;
}
/* активация слоя затемнения и модального блока */
.modal-open:checked ~ .modal-wrap:before,
.modal-open:checked ~ .modal-wrap .modal-overlay {
    display: block;
}
.modal-open:checked ~ .modal-wrap .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    top: 20%;
}
/* элементы модального окна */
.modal-dialog {
    background: radial-gradient( #3daee7, #1070b9);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 500px;
    left: 50%;
    top: -100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-out;
    z-index: 103;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 0 20px 75px 20px ;
}


.modal-header h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
   padding: 15px 20px 30px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}




.btn-search {background: radial-gradient( #3daee7, #1070b9); border-radius: 22px; color:#FFF; width:44px; height:44px; line-height:44px; text-align: center; font-size:24px; display: block; cursor: pointer;}
.btn-search:hover{text-shadow: 0 0px 10px  #fff; tansition: all .3s linear; -webkit-transition: all .3s linear; -moz-transition: all .3s linear; }


.body{background: #000;}
```

```html
<label class="btn" for="modal-1">Открыть</label>
<!-- Модальное окно -->
<div class="modal">
  <input class="modal-open" id="modal-1" type="checkbox" hidden>
  <div class="modal-wrap" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    <label class="modal-overlay" for="modal-1"></label>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Поиск по сайту </h2>
        <label class="btn-close" for="modal-1" aria-hidden="true"></label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          
              
                    <form class="searchtop" method="post">  

                          <div class="inp-wrp">
                           <input class="searchtop" autocomplete="off" name="story" placeholder="Введите ваш запрос..." type="search">
                           <div class="searchline"></div>
                           </div>
                           <input  type="hidden" name="do" value="search" >
                           <input  type="hidden" name="subaction" value="search" >
                            <button type="submit" id="btntop">Найти</button>
                      
                   </form>
```

Линия там же где и в примере:

```css
.searchtop {width: 100%; height: 44px; line-height: 44px; border: none; border-radius: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; background: transparent; color:#fff;  font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 30px;}

#btntop { width: 100%;  border: 1px solid #fff; background: transparent; vertical-align: middle; }


/*Hover эффект*/
.searchline{
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 0%;
    left:50%;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
form input:hover ~ .searchline{width: 100%;}


/* Стили модального окна */
.modal-header h2 {
    color: #fff;  
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;    
    margin: 0;
}
/* кнопка закрытия окна */
.modal .btn-close:before {
    content: '\2715';
    font-family: FontAwesome ;
     font-size: 1.7em;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 44px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: -5px;
}
.modal .btn-close:hover {
   text-shadow: 0 0px 10px  #fff; tansition: all .3s linear; -webkit-transition: all .3s linear; -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
}
/* слой затемнения */
.modal-wrap:before {
    content: "";
    display: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 101;
}
.modal-overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 102;
}
/* активация слоя затемнения и модального блока */
.modal-open:checked ~ .modal-wrap:before,
.modal-open:checked ~ .modal-wrap .modal-overlay {
    display: block;
}
.modal-open:checked ~ .modal-wrap .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    top: 20%;
}
/* элементы модального окна */
.modal-dialog {
    background: radial-gradient( #3daee7, #1070b9);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 500px;
    left: 50%;
    top: -100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-out;
    z-index: 103;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 0 20px 75px 20px ;
}


.modal-header h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
   padding: 15px 20px 30px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}




.btn-search {background: radial-gradient( #3daee7, #1070b9); border-radius: 22px; color:#FFF; width:44px; height:44px; line-height:44px; text-align: center; font-size:24px; display: block; cursor: pointer;}
.btn-search:hover{text-shadow: 0 0px 10px  #fff; tansition: all .3s linear; -webkit-transition: all .3s linear; -moz-transition: all .3s linear; }


.body{background: #000;}
```

```html
<label class="btn" for="modal-1">Открыть</label>
<!-- Модальное окно -->
<div class="modal">
  <input class="modal-open" id="modal-1" type="checkbox" hidden>
  <div class="modal-wrap" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    <label class="modal-overlay" for="modal-1"></label>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Поиск по сайту </h2>
        <label class="btn-close" for="modal-1" aria-hidden="true"></label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          
              
                    <form class="searchtop" method="post">  

                           <input class="searchtop" autocomplete="off" name="story" placeholder="Введите ваш запрос..." type="search">
                           <input  type="hidden" name="do" value="search" >
                           <input  type="hidden" name="subaction" value="search" >
                            <button type="submit" id="btntop">Найти</button>
                      <div class="searchline"></div>
                   </form>

 

      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Линия должна появлятся под окошком ввода, там где нужно вводить текст, там где линия под словами "Введите ваш запрос", таким образом линия станет толще в 2 раза, и только при наведении на это самое окошко

Comment: @ZinMe Добавил еще один пример

Comment: Да, спасибо, это то что надо, я пытался этот эффект в input вставить, а оказывается нужно было создать отдельный блок с линией